# Open file write to it and display results in the console

Tags: c

I'm new to C, what I try to do is to get user code input, remove all comments from the code and then get the new code and keep working with it.
So I create a function that remove the comments, print the result code to a file and return that file.
It looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum status {OUT, IN_STRING, LEFT_SLASH, IN_COMMENT, RIGHT_STAR, IN_CPP_COM};

FILE *trim_comments(){

    int c;
    int state = OUT;
    FILE *clean_code;
    clean_code = fopen("clean-code.c", "w+");

    while ( (c = getchar()) != EOF )
        switch ( state ) {
            case OUT:
                if ( c == '/' ) {
                    state = LEFT_SLASH;
                } else {
                    fputc(c, clean_code);
                    if ( c == '\"' )
                        state = IN_STRING;
                }
            break;

            case LEFT_SLASH :

                if ( c == '*' ) {
                    state = IN_COMMENT;
                } else if ( c == '/'){
                    state = IN_CPP_COM;
                } else {
                    fputc('/', clean_code);
                    fputc(c, clean_code);
                    state = OUT;
                }

            break;

            case IN_COMMENT :

            if ( c == '*' ) {
                state = RIGHT_STAR;
            }

            break;

            case IN_CPP_COM :
                if ( c == '\n' ) {
                    state = OUT;
                    fputc('\n', clean_code);
                }
            break;

            case RIGHT_STAR :
                if ( c == '/' ) {
                    state = OUT;
                } else if ( c != '*' ) {
                    state = IN_COMMENT;
                }
            break;

            case IN_STRING :
                if ( c == '\"' )
                    state = OUT;
                fputc(c, clean_code);
            break;

        } 

        return clean_code;

}
```

Then In the main I get the file, and want just for now to print it to the console:

```
#include <stdio.h>

FILE *trim_comments();

int main(void){

    int c;

    FILE *file = trim_comments();

    while  ( (c = fgetc(file)) != EOF ) {
        printf("%c", c);
    }

    return 0;

}
```

When I run the program the file `clean-code.c` is created, but it's blank. Also I don't see anything in the console, the program is just wait:
[image]

Also the makefile:

```
myprog : par.o trim-comments.o
        gcc -g -Wall -pedantic -ansi par.o trim-comments.o -o myprog

par.o : par.c
        gcc -c -Wall -pedantic -ansi par.c -o par.o

trim-comments.o : trim-comments.c
        gcc -c -Wall -pedantic -ansi trim-comments.c -o trim-comments.o <test.c
```

`test.c` is the file that contains the user code and some comments that I want to remove..

Comment: You tagged and asked about C. Do you want to learn how to do that in C? Or do you just need the goal achieved and would be open to proposals how to do that with other tools? E.g. sed, awk, perl.

Comment: @Yunnosch Yes I want to learn how to do it with C..

Comment: Also You need rewind file.

Comment: @xing I did it, now the file clean-code.c is not empty. However the printf doesn't print the file to the console..

Comment: try `rewind(clean_code);` before `return clean_code;`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Work! what exactly this functions does?

Comment: See [rewind](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/rewind)

Comment: when calling the function: `fopen()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: code should cleanup after it self, not depend on the OS to clean up after the program exits.  I.E. before exiting the program, call: `fclose( file );`

Comment: this line: `FILE *trim_comments();` just before the 'main()` function is telling the compiler that there could be any number of parameters to the `trim_comments()` function.   It would be better written as: `FILE *trim_comments( void );`

Comment: this line, in `main()` `printf("%c", c);` is calling a very heavy duty/slow function.  Suggest using: `putc( c, stdout );`

Comment: the fopen mode of `w+` will truncate the file before anything else.  To avoid that problem use 'r+'

Comment: there is a major problem with the logic of the posted code.   The file pointer is not correctly (re)positioned between the reads and the writes.  Strongly suggest opening two files 1) the original code to read and  2) the modified file to write

Comment: this text `< test.c` in the makefile, is wrong and should be removed